# How do you work with accurate image sizes when you have windows scaling on 125% or larger

Tags: web, windows-10, resolution, scaling, dpi

how do you work with accurate image sizes when you have windows scaling on 125% or larger.

Because i have a 1920x1080 resolution monitor without scaling to 125% my desktop applications (photoshop,chrome) and everything is tiny. In addition 
website images that look great at non-windows scaling now appear too large and fuzzy with scaling on. I'm using chrome.
Is it possible to use media query's to detect
this and shrink the images so it looks normal.
Zooming chrome to 80% looks perfect when 125% size is on (with my images).

Understand this question?
Ok.

Comment: It is basic physics.  If an image is too large then it has to be rescaled as well, now losing image details.  I suppose web sites will eventually adopt image sizes that look better on high resolution monitors, perhaps even choose one from a set of images that were tuned to fit a dpi well, it is getting there.  Until then, you can simply move the monitor further away from you so it is not so obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment